# How to retrieve parsed HTML source for a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, c

I've managed to make a request using sockets on an https connection to a web page by sending: `GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: random_website.com/my_page_of_interest\nConnection: close\n\n`

However the content I get is almost all very complex javascript(likely generated).

Is there an easy way to get HTML contents of a **parsed** webpage using C or C++?

Comment: No, there isn't an easy way